# Comparatives and superlatives for the word "statistic"

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree, ielts

Let's say, there was a bar chart giving 2 different pieces of data for 3 groups.

[image: a bar chart giving 2 different pieces of data for 3 groups]

---

> **- `Monkeys` was the `______________` statistic.**

---

*If you needed to complete the sentence above with **`a superlative adjective`**, what would you fill in the blank?*

Comment: A ***statistic*** is [a fact or piece of data obtained from a study of a large quantity of numerical data](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/statistic) - i.e ***a value***. Your chart gives two such values for each of three different animals, so the number of ***statistics*** is equal for each type of animal. What you actually mean is ***Monkeys were the most common animal***. For loose usage you would probably be understood if you said ***Monkey was the highest statistic***, but it's a bit of a roundabout way of expressing things.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite. "Statistic" is a noun and its adjective "statistical". The comparative and superlative of that is "most statistical" and "most statistical".

Comment: I'd say "the most salient" statistic, or better, "the most salient feature".

Comment: @WS2: I can (just about) imagine the comparative in a context like *He takes a **more statistical approach** to analysis than I do,* but other than that the usage makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, @FumbleFingers. Your comment is very helpful :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about "The argument is based on much guesswork, what we need is a more statistical approach". or "Of the three appraisal scenarios, A,B & C I think that B is the most statistical".  Another might be where statistics are being compared to a mathematical proof e.g. "The mathematical argument tells us one thing, but a more statistical one says something else".

Comment: @DanBron Nice one! Unfortunately, we just need only one word here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could easily (and best) use "**least/most/more**" along with ***another descriptor*** that defines the noun "**statistic**".

> -Monkey was the ***most counted*** statistic.
>
> -Monkey was the ***most predictable*** statistic.

Use of lone superlatives like "**lowest**", "**greatest**", or "**highest**" by themselves might work, but it becomes vague/unclear as to what the superlative refers (the count statistic, the animal category statistic, or the height of the bars in the chart).

> -Monkey was the ***highest*** statistic.